# The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode ()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing code which uploads file from one server to another, Following is my code:

```
      string CompleteDPath = "ftp://ExampleURL/photos/";
        string UName = "USerName";
        string PWD = "Password";
        WebRequest reqObj = WebRequest.Create(CompleteDPath + fileName);
        reqObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        reqObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UName, PWD);
        FileStream streamObj = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(path));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[streamObj.Length + 1];
        streamObj.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        streamObj.Close();
        streamObj = null;
        reqObj.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqObj = null;
```

But first time it works fine, but next time it throws error as bellow:
The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode ()

Can you please tell me whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use

reqObj.UsePassive = false;

Comment: I don't recommend doing this, except temporarily to help find the real issue. As mentioned, 227 is not an error, but I assume that's being returned in the error message as the last successful command. The actual error may be a connection issue or something else. Refer to this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209638/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-227-entering-passive-mode-500-oops-vs-util